# Buffer with PostGIS in the form of a pentagon or hexagon

Tags: postgis, buffer

In PostGIS, the **ST_Buffer** function allows a user to specify the segements per quadrant. However, only polygons with multiples of 4 (4, 8, 12, 16, etc) are allowed.

How would you buffer a point to a indivisiable 4 sided polygon.

Feeding a decimal number like 1.5 (for a hexagon) to the *quad_segs* parameter does not work as it seems to simply ignore the decimals and just makes 1 out of it.

Using PostGIS 2.5 and PostgreSQL 11.3

Comment: You could choose 4 or 2 times the number of sides, then filter, e.g., choose 3 for hexagon or 20 for Pentagon...

Comment: You mean I can just settle with 12 instead of 6 and with 20 instead of 5? That's not really satisfactory to me, but can this be further processed by reducing the abount of sides from 12 to 6 somehow?

Comment: Regular (equilateral & equiangular) Polygons are no magic, their inherent circular symmetry makes them easy to create; while not at *C* speed, [this](https://gist.github.com/geozelot/ddf88a9ae0438d7a46f176e9555ce7a1) function should be a lot faster than any filtering on buffers.

Comment: I did not suggest you settle for something different, I suggested that you start with something that has vertices in the right positions and extract the values you want to keep ("filter"). @geozealot is right that doing the math yourself would be faster.

Comment: @Vince I really should have named me geoze**a**lot, professionally - not the first time someone assumed that apparently not-too-bad-a-name - but I liked the ocelot (Ozelot in German) so much...

Comment: ha! tiny phone characters and auto-correct prompts in the morning are a bad combination.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a plain SQL equivalent of the `MakeAGon` function suggested in the comments above.  It creates a pentagon (5 sides) of radius 2 centred at (10,10).  Those values can be changed to whatever is needed.

```
SELECT ST_MakePolygon( ST_MakeLine( ARRAY_AGG( 
    ST_Point( 10 + 2 * COSD(90 + i * 360 / 5 ), 
              10 + 2 * SIND(90 + i * 360 / 5 )  ))))
  FROM generate_series(0, 5) AS s(i);
```

Comment: Martin Davis, can I specify and use the features you have published on this site in my github project or do I need to do it some other way?

Comment: Cyril, feel free to use anything I post to this site.

Comment: Got it, thanks for the reply. I'll leave links to your features as far as possible....

Answer (score 1):

How about this approach:

```
WITH
tbla AS (SELECT ST_ExteriorRing(ST_Buffer(geom,0.01)) geom FROM (SELECT ST_SetSrid(ST_MakePoint(0.0, 0.0),4326) geom) foo),
tblb AS (SELECT i, ST_LineInterpolatePoint(geom, (i-1.0)/4) geom FROM tbla
    JOIN generate_series (1, 4) AS step(i) ON true)
    SELECT ST_PointsInStarPolygon(geom) geom FROM (SELECT ST_Collect(geom) geom FROM tblb) a;
```

Or this approach:

```
WITH
tbla AS (SELECT ST_ExteriorRing(ST_Buffer(geom,0.01)) geom FROM (SELECT ST_SetSrid(ST_MakePoint(0.0, 0.0),4326) geom) foo),
tblb AS (SELECT generate_series (0, 4) as steps), 
tblc AS (SELECT steps AS stp, ST_LineInterpolatePoint(geom, steps/(SELECT count(steps)::float-1 FROM tblb)) geom FROM tbla, tblb GROUP BY tblb.steps, geom)
    SELECT ST_PointsInStarPolygon(geom) geom FROM (SELECT ST_Collect(geom) geom FROM tblc) a;
```

Be sure to set the buffer radius in the coordinate system, the location of your point and the number of edges, you can even create your custom function,

and give it a proper name :-)...

Original spatial solutions...

Comment: Very impressive! Thanks a lot for this solution. 
If I have a table of points already, I can probably skip the generation of tbla I guess and reference my point table in the tblc statement directly, I guess.

Comment: This approach is suitable for a single geometric point - as you indicated in your question condition, I believe that for a set of points you need to approach it a bit differently and as a result, you need to ask another question with different conditions (for a set of points) and I think you will get different answers to it too...

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're asking. The title says pentagon or hexagon but "How would you buffer a point to a indivisiable 4 sided polygon." sounds like a square:

```
select row_number() over() as id, st_expand(geom, 5000.0) as geom
from osm.pofw
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Based on dr_jts response, I propose the following version of the design and name of the new spatial SQL function:

---

This simple spatial SQL function takes as input both one geospatial point and many points (POINT-EPSG:4326) and outputs transformed circumscribed polygons (POLYGON-EPSG:4326) with set radius of circle and required number of edges.

Create a spatial SQL function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ST_RegularPolygonInscribedInCircle(
geom GEOMETRY,
radius float,
edge integer)
RETURNS GEOMETRY AS
$BODY$
WITH 
    tbla AS (SELECT $1)
    SELECT ST_MakePolygon(ST_MakeLine(ARRAY_AGG(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(ST_X(geom) + radius * COSD(90 + i * 360/edge), 
              ST_Y(geom) + radius * SIND(90 + i * 360/edge)),4326)))) geom FROM generate_series(0, edge) AS s(i);
$BODY$
LANGUAGE SQL;
```

Run:

```
SELECT ST_RegularPolygonInscribedInCircle(geom, 0.01, 5) geom FROM <point_table>
```

Note: The author and developer of the function itself is Martin Davis (dr jts (https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/14766/dr-jts))!